# Cause vim to exit on final bd

Tags: vim

I would like to exit on `:bd` if i'm on the last buffer. I am not very familiar with vimscript, but I assume something must be bound to the autocmd BufDelete.

Answer (score 1):

From [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/668612/270158):

```
:au BufDelete * if len(filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'buflisted(v:val)')) == 1 | quit | endif
```

Add the above snippet to your `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: This doesn't actually work for me because of the empty buffer. Should be: `autocmd BufDelete * if len(filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'empty(bufname(v:val)) && buflisted(v:val)')) == 1 | quit | endif`. Did it work work for you?

Comment: @cdosborn Yes, it works fine for me. Either way, it’s not something I use. I have `<leader>q` mapped to `:q<cr>` and it’s always easier to reach for me.

Comment: This is incomplete. If you open vim, and open :help, nothing is displayed. See [here](http://superuser.com/questions/671457/vim-autocommand-on-bufdelete-prevents-opening-help-window)

Comment: To get the total number of buflisted buffers, you could also use `len(getbufinfo({'buflisted':1}))`

Comment: [Mapping to close vim upon closing last buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31619790/quit-vim-when-all-buffers-are-closed-after-bd)